# Show alert in asp.net based on result from stored proc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am wanting to show an alert based on the output param of a stored proc. If it is true, then I want to show an alert. Baffled by this in honesty.

Here is the code I have so far, it does not like the Response.Redirect as it returns an error regarding it potentially being unsafe:

```
public ActionResult NewCountry(string button,string Country,string Notes)
{
    switch (button)
    {
        case "Save":
            bool exists = InsertCountry(Country, Notes);
            if (exists)
            {
                //Something
                return Redirect("/Maintenance/Maintenance/Country");
            }
            else
                return Redirect("/Maintenance/Maintenance/Country");
        case "Cancel":
            //Need to redirect to the countries page. 
            return Redirect("/Maintenance/Maintenance/Country");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Can anyone advise of the correct way to show a confirmation alert in ASP.net?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I laughed when I saw response.redirect(js alert).  Thats just awesome

Comment: `Response.Redirect()` accepts a *URI* as a parameter.  A snippet of JS code inside a tag is not a URI.

Comment: @JonH glad to bring some entertainment for you and no need to apologise. This is not my usual area of expertise, so if you have the answer, and care to share it, I would be very grateful.

Comment: To place data somewhere it will be available **after a redirect**, you may also want to consider using **TempData**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really one correct way, it really depends on the architecture you have going on for the front of the site, e.g. is it based on CSHTML/Ajax/Angular something else.

The code you have shown is a bit of mix of various ideas. One way to tidy it up would be to do something like this.

```
public ActionResult NewCountry(string button,string Country,string Notes)
    {
        switch (button)
        {
            case "Save":
                bool exists = InsertCountry(Country, Notes);
                if (exists)
                {
                    return Redirect("/Maintenance/Maintenance/Country?alert=true");
                }
                else
                    return Redirect("/Maintenance/Maintenance/Country");
            case "Cancel":
                //Need to redirect to the countries page. 
                return Redirect("/Maintenance/Maintenance/Country");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

As you can see I've added ?alert=true to the page URL. You would then run some javascript on page load to look for this parameter and if it exists show an alert box.

It's important in all web programming to keep a clear idea of what happens on the server, what happens on the browser, and how you are communicating between the two.

Comment: Thanks for this, that is all I needed, I was baffled as how to communicate from the server to push that to the client, as you can probably tell, this is quite new to me.This is really simple and does exactly what I need and will be a great help in the future too, thank you very much! Will accept as the answer as soon as I can.